# Why doesn't this simple java fork join pool work?

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I am about to test this forkjoin pool but it doesn't work fine. I wonder why?

This is the class which I made to get an array and adds 3 to its elements:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invokeAll;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class t extends RecursiveAction{

    private final int array[];
    private final int th=4;

    public t (int array[]){
        this.array=array;
    }

    protected void compdir(){

        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i]=array[i]+3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute(){
        int cont=1;

        System.out.println("array="+(array[0])+","+array[array.length-1]);


        System.out.println("cont="+cont);
        if (array.length<th){      
            compdir();

        } else {

            int spil=(array[0]+array[(array.length-1)])/2;
            int array1[]=new int[spil];
            int array2[]=new int[spil];
            for (int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
                array1[i]=array[i];
            }
            for (int i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
                array2[i]=array[i+(array1.length)];
            }
            invokeAll(new t(array1) , new t(array2));
            cont++;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the main class:

```
package nt;

import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class Nt {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(processors) + " processor"
                + (processors != 1 ? "s are " : " is ")
                + "available");

        int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
        t test=new t(arr);

        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        pool.invoke(test);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Takes " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                " milliseconds.");

    }

}
```

Comment: It would help if you explain what doesn't work fine.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

Comment: Can you add that to your original question so we can see the full stacktrace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:536)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportResult(ForkJoinTask.java:596)

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportResult(ForkJoinTask.java:596)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:640)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:1521)
 at nt.Nt.main(Nt.java:22)

Comment: Can you edit your original question. Comments are useless for complex text like a stacktrace or code. Also your code is not complete.

So can you modify your original question and post the full code and the full stacktrace. If that doesn't work, just create a new answer where you post all your information.

Comment: Ok. just a second please...

Comment: sorry. cannot paste the stack trace.but this is my full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new array for each task. Although the *contents* of these new arrays is set to be the same as in the input array, changing the values in these *new* arrays will NOT affect the values in the *input* array.

You have to make sure that ALL tasks ONLY work on the INPUT array. The tasks only differ in the elements of the input array that they care about. In this example, the range that each task is working on is specified by 'min' and 'max' :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class Nt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(processors) + " processor"
            + (processors != 1 ? "s are " : " is ")
            + "available");

        int arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
        t test=new t(arr);

        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        pool.invoke(test);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Takes " + (endTime - startTime) + 
            " milliseconds.");

    }
}
class t extends RecursiveAction{


    private final int array[];
    private final int min;
    private final int max;
    private final int th=4;

    public t (int array[]){
        this(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    public t (int array[], int min, int max){
        this.array=array;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;

        System.out.println("Task to handle range "+min+" to "+max);
    }

    protected void compdir(){

        for (int i=min;i<max;i++){
            array[i]=array[i]+3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute(){
        if (max-min<th) {      
            compdir();
        } else {

            int center = min + (max - min) / 2;
            invokeAll(new t(array, min, center) , new t(array, center+1, max));
        }
    }

}
```